# Eclipse Git search text changed files

Tags: git, eclipse, search, commit, egit

Is it a way to search for commits in which files have been changed (code removed or added) using text search?

**For example:**
I have connected to my teams repositorie and now i can see the history of commits. I want to search a commit, in which the line "isGlossaryTermUsed" has changed (added or deleted). I know that i can search it using "search tool", but only if there is such line in code and with this way i cant see what changes the commiter added or deleted.

My english is poor , i hope i formed the question correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` has the `-G <pattern>` option ([docs here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt)) :

it will list only commits for which the *diff* contains said pattern.

You can combine it with other `git log` options :

```
# will list commits along with the files they modified :
git log --name-only/--name-status
# will list a file *only* if its diff matches <pattern>
git log --name-only/--name-status -G <pattern>


# will list commits along with the diff (the 'patch') of the commit :
git log -p
# will show the diff of file where <pattern> appears
git log -p -G <pattern>
```

There is also the `-S <pattern>` option ([docs right next to -G](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt)) which adds an additional twist :
a commit is kept only if the number of times that `<pattern>` appears *changes*.

This second option will keep the commits where the pattern appears or disappears, and ignore commits where it is only moved.

---

There may be a field which offers this option somewhere in the GUI for git (I am not familiar with Eclipse git), look for a field which would say `-S`, `-G` or `pickaxe`.